# jqGrid columns do not expand to setGridWidth after 1 column hidden in IE8 only

Tags: javascript, html, jqgrid, internet-explorer-8

I've a jqGrid v3.7.2, after hiding a column using

```
.jqGrid('hideCol', infoName);
```

and setting the grid width using

```
.setGridWidth(setWidth, true)
```

The columns do not expand to fill the table width in IE8 only.

The table width is correct. The tbody/col widths comes short.

Any way to solve this problem via CSS? Or is there another method in jqGrid to correct this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution from:
[IE8 isn't resizing tbody or thead when a column is hidden in a table with table-layout:fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654103/ie8-isnt-resizing-tbody-or-thead-when-a-column-is-hidden-in-a-table-with-table-l)

Simplified below for my purpose, added right after I hide the column:

```
// IE8 Fix, tbody not equal to table width for hidden col
            $('#tblGrid_Subject, td[aria-describedby=tblGrid_Subject]').attr('colSpan', '2');
```