# Table cells get hidden when total width is more than 100%

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a HTML table as given in the following code. This has 16 columns. I am setting the cell width using javascript. When the total width is less than 100%, it is working fine.

When the total width exceeds 100%, I want to display a `horizontal scroll bar`. But when I changed the width of the yellow highlighted cell from 5% to 30%, all the remaining cells get hidden instead of appearance of a scroll bar.

**QUESTIONS**:

1. Why the scrollbar is not appearing at present ?
2. How can we make it to work appropriately by showing `scroll bar`? (Also the two columns after the yellow column should `visible`; not hidden)

Note: The issue is noted in **IE8**.

Note: Refer http://jsfiddle.net/Lijo/dYSfN/2/ for code. This does not show the issue. For visualizing the issue, please copy the code into a html file and open using IE8

**UPDATE**

While `hiding a column`, remaining columns width automatically adjusts to table width in Firefox and Chrome but not in IE8. In IE8 the table width `shrinks`.

http://srikanthgade.blogspot.in/2010/09/ie8-standards-table-layout-fixed.html#!/2010/09/ie8-standards-table-layout-fixed.html

Issue Details

When Yellow Highlighted Cell Width is 5%

[image]

When Yellow Highlighted Cell Width is 30%

[image]

**STYLE**

```
   .gridTableBorder
   {
        overflow:scroll;
        border: 2px solid green;
   }

    /*GridView Tables*/
    .resultGridTable
    {
        table-layout: fixed; /*Needed along with word wrap */
    }

    .resultGridTable th
    {
        background-color: #A7A7A6;
        color: #ffffff;
        padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;
        font: bold 9pt Arial;
        border: 1px solid red;
        word-wrap: break-word;
    }

    .resultGridTable td
    {
        padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
        font: normal 9pt Arial;
        word-wrap: break-word;
        border: 1px solid blue;
    }
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
    $(document).ready(function () {


        //Width Setting
        var numberOfColumns = 16;
        $('.resultGridTable th, .resultGridTable td').each(function (i) {


            if (i % numberOfColumns == 0) {
                $(this).css('width', '1%');
            }

            if (i % numberOfColumns == 1) {
                $(this).css('width', '10%');
            }

            if (i % numberOfColumns == 2) {
                $(this).css('width', '9%');

            }

            if (i % numberOfColumns == 3) {
                $(this).css('width', '8%');
                $(this).css('background-color', 'orange');
            }

            if (i % numberOfColumns == 4) {
                $(this).css('width', '6%');
            }
            if (i % numberOfColumns == 5) {
                $(this).css('width', '8%');
            }
            if (i % numberOfColumns == 6) {
                $(this).css('width', '5%');
            }
            if (i % numberOfColumns == 7) {
                $(this).css('width', '5%');
            }
            if (i % numberOfColumns == 8) {
                $(this).css('width', '5%');
            }

            ///
            if (i % numberOfColumns == 9) {
                $(this).css('width', '7%');
            }
            if (i % numberOfColumns == 10) {
                $(this).css('width', '8%');
                $(this).css('background-color', 'orange');
            }

            if (i % numberOfColumns == 11) {
                $(this).css('width', '5%');
            }
            if (i % numberOfColumns == 12) {
                $(this).css('width', '5%');
            }

            if (i % numberOfColumns == 13) {
                $(this).css('width', '30%');
                $(this).css('background-color', 'Yellow');
            }

            if (i % numberOfColumns == 14) {
                $(this).css('width', '7%');
            }

            if (i % numberOfColumns == 15) {
                $(this).css('width', '7%');
            }

        }
        );


        //Hide Is Summary Row Column
        var selectedElements = $("tr").find("th:first, td:first");
        $(selectedElements).hide();


    }
    );
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
<form method="post" action="LocalTaxReport.aspx" id="form1">
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="container">
        <div id="centralContainer">
            <div id="mainContainer">
                <div id="contentHolderDiv" class="contentHolderDiv">
                    <div id="resultContainer" class="resultContainerDiv">
                        <div id="gridDiv" class="gridTableBorder">
                            <div>
                                <table class="resultGridTable" cellspacing="0" id="detailContentPlaceholder_grdLocalTaxReport"
                                    style="border-collapse: collapse;">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th scope="col">
                                            IsSummaryRow
                                        </th>
                                        <th scope="col">
                                            Associate
                                        </th>
                                        <th scope="col">
                                            My Amount
                                        </th>
                                        <th scope="col">
                                            Federal Withholding
                                        </th>
                                        <th scope="col">
                                            Social Security
                                        </th>
                                        <th scope="col">
                                            Medicaring
                                        </th>
                                        <th scope="col">
                                            State Tax
                                        </th>
                                        <th scope="col">
                                            County Tax
                                        </th>
                                        <th scope="col">
                                            City Tax
                                        </th>
                                        <th scope="col">
                                            Total
                                        </th>
                                        <th scope="col">
                                            State
                                        </th>
                                        <th scope="col">
                                            State Code
                                        </th>
                                        <th scope="col">
                                            County
                                        </th>
                                        <th scope="col">
                                            County Code
                                        </th>
                                        <th scope="col">
                                            City
                                        </th>
                                        <th scope="col">
                                            City Code
                                        </th>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            False
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            Mary Dryden
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            $3450
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            $32
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            $5
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            $2
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            $10
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            $1
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            $2
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            $3400
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            Arkansas
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            AR
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            Benton
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            04567
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            Bentonville
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            23156
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: Do you have other CSS affecting this that is not posted here? I ask, because I do not see the behavior you describe when I set up your code and run it on IE8. What is the CSS for all the wrapper elements this table is buried in?

Comment: @ScottS I don't have any other CSS. All the code is posted here. From the answer of Enrico it seems like it is reproducbale

Comment: When I set up a page and view in IE8 at 30%, it just forces adjusts other table cell widths to keep the table at 100% width. I'm on Windows 7 viewing in IE9 set to show IE8 browser mode. So I guess I cannot be of any help.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I tried to achieve the desired effect you had with few modification and I am going to describe it here.

1. You need to set the `doctype`. A DOCTYPE Declaration is mandatory for most current markup languages and without one it is impossible to reliably validate a document or determine what rules to apply.
2. You are not seeing the scroll bars because the width of table is not set. The div by default takes `100%`. Now set the `overflow` property to the div and then set the width of the table to `120%` (that exceeds the div's `100%`) to see the scroll bars.
3. Table width of `120%` doesn't mean you can sum of all column width to `120`. Since the `table-layout:fixed`, You need to tally sum of all columns width to `100` even if you set the table width as `120%`.
4. In you code you were setting the width of all columns and rows, instead apply width only to `th` or the first row which will apply with to all columns in all rows (entire table).
5. Modified your code from using `if..if..if` to use `if..else if..else if`

**Note:** 4 and 5 are improvements from the existing code.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/FP7MF/2/embedded/result/

**Full Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1">
    <title>My Report </title>
    <style type="text/css">

        /*GridView Tables*/
        .resultGridTable
        {
            table-layout: fixed; 
            width: 130%;
        }

        .resultGridTable th
        {
            background-color: #A7A7A6;
            color: #ffffff;
            padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;
            font: bold 9pt Arial;
            border: 1px solid red;
            word-wrap: break-word;
        }

        .resultGridTable td
        {
            padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
            font: normal 9pt Arial;
            word-wrap: break-word;
            border: 1px solid blue;
        }

        #gridDiv div { overflow: auto;  }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="container">
                <div id="centralContainer">
                    <div id="mainContainer">
                        <div id="contentHolderDiv" class="contentHolderDiv">
                            <div id="resultContainer" class="resultContainerDiv">
                                <div id="gridDiv" class="gridTableBorder">
                                    <div>
                                        <table class="resultGridTable" cellspacing="0" id="detailContentPlaceholder_grdLocalTaxReport"
                                             style="border-collapse: collapse;">
                                           <tr>
                                              <th scope="col">IsSummaryRow</th>
                                              <th scope="col">Associate</th>
                                              <th scope="col">My Amount</th>
                                              <th scope="col">Federal Withholding</th>
                                              <th scope="col">Social Security</th>
                                              <th scope="col">Medicaring</th>
                                              <th scope="col">State Tax</th>
                                              <th scope="col">County Tax</th>
                                              <th scope="col">City Tax</th>
                                              <th scope="col">Total</th>
                                              <th scope="col">State</th>
                                              <th scope="col">State Code</th>
                                              <th scope="col">County</th>
                                              <th scope="col">County Code</th>
                                              <th scope="col">City</th>
                                              <th scope="col">City Code</th>
                                           </tr>
                                           <tr>
                                               <td>False</td>
                                               <td>Mary Dryden</td>
                                               <td>$3450</td>
                                               <td>$32</td>
                                               <td>$5</td>
                                               <td>$2</td>
                                               <td>$10</td>
                                               <td>$1</td>
                                               <td>$2</td>
                                               <td>$3400</td>
                                               <td>Arkansas</td>
                                               <td>AR</td>
                                               <td>Benton</td>
                                               <td>04567</td>
                                               <td>Bentonville</td>
                                               <td>23156</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">


        $(document).ready(function () {


            //Width Setting
            var numberOfColumns = 16;
            $('.resultGridTable th').each(function (i) {

                if (i % numberOfColumns == 0) {
                    $(this).css('width', '1%');
                } else if (i % numberOfColumns == 1) {
                    $(this).css('width', '10%');
                } else if (i % numberOfColumns == 2) {
                    $(this).css('width', '9%');
                } else if (i % numberOfColumns == 3) {
                    $(this).css({'width': '8%', 'background-color': 'orange'});
                } else if (i % numberOfColumns == 4) {
                    $(this).css('width', '6%');
                } else if (i % numberOfColumns == 5) {
                    $(this).css('width', '8%');
                } else if (i % numberOfColumns == 6) {
                    $(this).css('width', '5%');
                } else if (i % numberOfColumns == 7) {
                    $(this).css('width', '5%');
                } else if (i % numberOfColumns == 8) {
                    $(this).css('width', '5%');
                } else if (i % numberOfColumns == 9) {
                    $(this).css('width', '7%');
                } else if (i % numberOfColumns == 10) {
                    $(this).css({'width': '8%', 'background-color': 'orange'});
                } else if (i % numberOfColumns == 11) {
                    $(this).css('width', '5%');
                } else if (i % numberOfColumns == 12) {
                    $(this).css('width', '5%');
                } else if (i % numberOfColumns == 13) {
                    $(this).css({'width': '8%', 'background-color': 'Yellow'});
                } else if (i % numberOfColumns == 14) {
                    $(this).css('width', '5%');
                } else if (i % numberOfColumns == 15) {
                    $(this).css('width', '5%');
                }

            });

            //Hide Is Summary Row Column
            var selectedElements = $("tr").find("th:first, td:first");
            $(selectedElements).hide();
        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When I made the width of yellow column as 30%, the columns after the yellow column are not displayed properly. How can we fix that?

Comment: Did you read the 3rd item which talks about the total sum of columns width not exceeding `100`.. It will work if you tally it to `100%`.

Comment: I don't think that is the reason. It is working fine in Chrome and Firefox even with 30%. Any rationale behind that?

Comment: @Lijo Every browser has their own rules and parsing technique. With table layout `fixed` and to make it work in IE. You need to tally it to `100`. Yes, lot of things works in FF and Chrome, but not in IE and this is one of them. 1. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2005/02/10/370721.aspx 2. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533002%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

It's not a perfect solution, but setting the table width to 120% and changing the column widths to be percentages of the table width (so they sum up to 100%) achieves the desired effect.

Comment: Can you explain why the scrollbar is not appearing when  width is 100%  ?

Answer (score 1):

forgive me if i am wrong, but can't this be solved by adding `overflow:scroll;` as a css rule for the div that contains the table?

Comment: It doesn't work. I tried .gridTableBorder { overflow:scroll; border: 2px solid green; }

Answer (score 1):

If we need to keep the table-layout as fixed in IE8, then below workaround needs to be added after hiding the columns:

```
:
:
$(selectedElements).hide();

// Add the workaround after the above line (or when hiding of columns is done).
$(".resultGridTable").attr("style","display:inline-table;");
window.setTimeout(function(){$(".resultGridTable").attr("style","");},0);
```

This is a bug in IE8, but it seems Microsoft has not responded on any resolution. If you find any information, please post it here.

But I have tried the workaround, still it does not give the desired output.

Just added it here, so that it might help in some more R&D.

References:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/iewebdevelopment/thread/f265c5b1-a45d-4949-85b2-86a97a884dc1/

Workaround:

[IE8 isn't resizing tbody or thead when a column is hidden in a table with table-layout:fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654103/ie8-isnt-resizing-tbody-or-thead-when-a-column-is-hidden-in-a-table-with-table)

http://srikanthgade.blogspot.in/2010/09/ie8-standards-table-layout-fixed.html

Comment: Please try IE8 in IE8 :-)  Please refer @ScottS comment also in the question

Comment: I have updated the post. Let me know whether it solved your issue.

Comment: That won't help. I need the table-layout to be fixed. Please explain why it works in Chrome and Firefox with table-layout (with some references to prove)

Comment: Found some references, might help in further R&D.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
.gridTableBorder
   {
        overflow:scroll;
        border: 2px solid green;
   }

    /*GridView Tables*/
    .resultGridTable
    {
        /*table-layout: fixed;*/ /*Needed along with word wrap */
    }

    .resultGridTable th
    {
        background-color: #A7A7A6;
        color: #ffffff;
        padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;
        font: bold 9pt Arial;
        border: 1px solid red;
        /*word-wrap: break-word;*/
    }

    .resultGridTable td
    {
        padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
        font: normal 9pt Arial;
        /*word-wrap: break-word;*/
        border: 1px solid blue;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {


        //Width Setting
        var numberOfColumns = 16;
        $('.resultGridTable th, .resultGridTable td').each(function (i) {


            if (i % numberOfColumns == 0) {
                $(this).css('width', '1%');
            }

            if (i % numberOfColumns == 1) {
                $(this).css('width', '10%');
            }

            if (i % numberOfColumns == 2) {
                $(this).css('width', '9%');

            }

            if (i % numberOfColumns == 3) {
                $(this).css('width', '8%');
                $(this).css('background-color', 'orange');
            }

            if (i % numberOfColumns == 4) {
                $(this).css('width', '6%');
            }
            if (i % numberOfColumns == 5) {
                $(this).css('width', '8%');
            }
            if (i % numberOfColumns == 6) {
                $(this).css('width', '5%');
            }
            if (i % numberOfColumns == 7) {
                $(this).css('width', '5%');
            }
            if (i % numberOfColumns == 8) {
                $(this).css('width', '5%');
            }

            ///
            if (i % numberOfColumns == 9) {
                $(this).css('width', '7%');
            }
            if (i % numberOfColumns == 10) {
                $(this).css('width', '8%');
                $(this).css('background-color', 'orange');
            }

            if (i % numberOfColumns == 11) {
                $(this).css('width', '5%');
            }
            if (i % numberOfColumns == 12) {
                $(this).css('width', '5%');
            }

            if (i % numberOfColumns == 13) {
                $(this).css('width', '30%');
                $(this).css('background-color', 'Yellow');
            }

            if (i % numberOfColumns == 14) {
                $(this).css('width', '7%');
            }

            if (i % numberOfColumns == 15) {
                $(this).css('width', '7%');
            }

        }
        );


        //Hide Is Summary Row Column
        var selectedElements = $("tr").find("th:first, td:first");
        $(selectedElements).hide();


    }
    );
</script>
</head>

<body>

<form method="post" action="LocalTaxReport.aspx" id="form1">
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="container">
        <div id="centralContainer">
            <div id="mainContainer">
                <div id="contentHolderDiv" class="contentHolderDiv">
                    <div id="resultContainer" class="resultContainerDiv">
                        <div id="gridDiv" class="gridTableBorder">
                            <div>
                                <table class="resultGridTable" cellspacing="1" id="detailContentPlaceholder_grdLocalTaxReport" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th scope="col">
                                            IsSummaryRow
                                        </th>
                                        <th scope="col">
                                            Associate
                                        </th>
                                        <th scope="col">
                                            My Amount
                                        </th>
                                        <th scope="col">
                                            Federal Withholding
                                        </th>
                                        <th scope="col">
                                            Social Security
                                        </th>
                                        <th scope="col">
                                            Medicaring
                                        </th>
                                        <th scope="col">
                                            State Tax
                                        </th>
                                        <th scope="col">
                                            County Tax
                                        </th>
                                        <th scope="col">
                                            City Tax
                                        </th>
                                        <th scope="col">
                                            Total
                                        </th>
                                        <th scope="col">
                                            State
                                        </th>
                                        <th scope="col">
                                            State Code
                                        </th>
                                        <th scope="col">
                                            County
                                        </th>
                                        <th scope="col">
                                            County Code
                                        </th>
                                        <th scope="col">
                                            City
                                        </th>
                                        <th scope="col">
                                            City Code
                                        </th>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            False
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            Mary Dryden
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            $3450
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            $32
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            $5
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            $2
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            $10
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            $1
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            $2
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            $3400
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            Arkansas
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            AR
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            Benton
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            04567
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            Bentonville
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            23156
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

I have just go through your problem, i have done some R&D on your code and css. I have just removed the table-layout:fixed and word-wrap:break-word;

Which was giving issue in IE8 as well as in IE7. In your screen shot 2 in which cell height is increased due to word-wrap:break-word.

In other browsers it was working fine. Just copy the code and check in your browser. If your needs are fulfilling without using table-layout:fixed and word-wrap css property than this is your solution.

@Lijo if i am missing something please let me know.

Comment: I cannot omit table-layout:fixed and word-wrap:break-word;