# Making IE8 re-render a table after removing a column

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, internet-explorer-8, repaint

I have a `table` like that:

```
<table width="100%" style="table-layout: fixed;" class="listtable"> ... </table>
```

After DOM load I remove the last `td`. Every browser, except IE8 of course, keeps the table at 100%.

IE8 just removes that column leaving the space and not adjusting the other columns. When inspecting the table, the `table` element is at 100% but the `tbody` is not. I already tried setting the width of the `tbody` after removing the column, but it had no effect.

**Does anyone know how I can force IE8 to re-render my table and stretch over 100%?**

*Note: I'm not in control of the generated html on the server-side so I need to use JavaScript here.*

Comment: Could you provide the full structure of the table with thead, tbody, th and td tags ? And the javascript code you are using ? And why not on http://jsfiddle.net/ :P

Answer (score 1):

I tried to create a jsfiddle with your need and I do not encounter your issue with IE9 with IE8 compatibility mode activated. Is that script working for you ? http://jsfiddle.net/3TpGt/2/

I created a code without use of javascript because I do not know if you want to use a library or not.

```
var table = document.getElementById("myTable");

var th = table.getElementsByTagName("th");
var thead = table.getElementsByTagName("thead");
var tbody= table.getElementsByTagName("tbody");
var tbody_tr= tbody[0].getElementsByTagName("tr");
var thead_tr = thead[0].getElementsByTagName("tr");

thead_tr[0].removeChild(th[th.length-1]);

var current_td = null;
for(i = 0; i < tbody_tr.length; i++) {
    current_td = tbody_tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
    tbody_tr[i].removeChild(current_td[current_td.length-1]);
}​
```

Then you can force the columns width after the deletion like :

```
th[0].width = '50%';
th[1].width = '50%';
```

**Or if you want that the browser automaticaly recalculate the columns width, change the style of your table :**

```
style="table-layout: auto; "
```

Comment: This seems to occur only in IE8 standards mode. Thanks! I found [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6079413/156481) which basically does the same thing by setting the table-layout. Though it really only works when using the `setTimeout`, very strange. You could add this link to your answer and I'll mark it has accepted! Thank you for your help!

Comment: Oh ok sorry I cannot help you then, because I have not the original IE8 installed on my computers ! You're welcome ^^